# failed to understand the use of a line in function working

Tags: javascript, function

```
<script>
function person(firstname,lastname,age,eyecolor)
{
    this.firstname=firstname;
    this.lastname=lastname;
    this.age=age;
    this.eyecolor=eyecolor;

    this.changeName=changeName;

    function changeName(name)
    {
        this.lastname=name;
    }
}
myMother=new person("Sally","Rally",48,"green");
document.writeln(myMother.lastname + " is " + myMother.age + " years old.");

myMother.changeName("Doe");
document.writeln(myMother.lastname);
</script>
```

here first i define the changeName() function body and call that function with parameter[myMother.changeName("Doe");]. it should work when it is called as i learned earlier.

but here why i need this line (this.changeName=changeName). if i remove it document.writeln(myMother.lastname) this command does not work. i failed to understand why this is happening and why this line (this.changeName=changeName) is used...

plz help me to find out the problem. As i am a beginner programmer in JavaScript let me know the procedure or a way how can i be better in JavaScript or which way i should follow to make myselt a better programmer. Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to use dot notation (so that you can do `myMother.changeName(name)` instead of `changeName(myMother, name)`), the function has to be set as a property of the object. `this.changeName = changeName` sets the function as a property of the object being created.

---

A better way would be to set it on the prototype once, which would then make it available to all objects being created from the `person` constructor:

```
person.prototype.changeName = function (name) {
    this.lastname = name;
}
```

That way, we don't have to re-create the function every time we create a new object.

Comment: i understand..thanks a lot.. :)
i am new in javascript. i hv finished almost the basic things of JavaScript. but i dont understand how should i proceed. i m confused what and how can i improve my skill and feeling scattered.  do u plz tell me a proper and structured way so that i can make myself better in javaScript.

Comment: @skipperkhan - `function changename()` just defines a stand-alone function. `this.changeName = changeName` assigns that function as a property of `myMother`. You can do all of that in one step: `this.changeName = function (name) { this.lastname = name }`. But as I pointed out, using the prototype is a better solution.

Comment: @skipperkhan - To get a solid understanding of basic JavaScript, I suggest you read Cody Linley's excellent [JavaScript Enlightenment](http://www.javascriptenlightenment.com/) book.

Comment: @skipperkhan - Check out these [amazing free books](http://jsbooks.revolunet.com/).